# WPF smerging GUI during mouse drag

Tags: wpf, colors, mouseover

The problem with the GUI (WPF) is that colors are smerging on the screen without the drag of the mouse.

The video can be seen via the link:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApQ4XJuBofwuoRs6ChP7Bl4PKs9j?e=9JPtf1

We don't know what might be causing it.

It is happening only on a laptop, with the newest drivers and on latest Win 10.

Comment: Need more information about your app, code, what did you try, is it reproducing on different machines, etc'.

Comment: No, we cannot reproduce it at work. It is on (for now) just one client computer. 

We tried updating drivers, we tried connecting different monitors (I didn't have any hope in it anyway, but tried anyway), tried forcing refresh on windows, since it cures black areas on Win7 for instance, no, nothing helps.

We need some ideas on what to suggest to the client to try.

Comment: Yes, forgot, we use WPF, mostly vanilla, net framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Maybe has something to do with DPI: https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/PerMonitorDPI/readme.md Otherwise I would suspect that client cant support graphics(?): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/graphics-rendering-tiers?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: The thing was DirectX, there are sound drivers on some computers that modify the DirectX. When there are such drivers (I forgot exactly which ones, but it is usually on high-end motherboards) the only solution that I found is either uninstall the drivers or turn off DirectX rendering and use the software mode. So we made a configuration that turns of DirectX if the customer has such problem, in our case it was two clients. And our app could work normally with just software render, since it is not 3d hungry.